# Pentaho Connection to DB Reset

Tags: database, connection, pentaho, jobs, pentaho-spoon

I would like to know, if there are any tools in the Design Tools from Pentaho spoon, that can be usefull to close a db connection and reset it, or , a tool that forces a new connection.

Why?  We got jobs that takes a long time to Execute so, often we are timed out, after each job, we would like to restabilish the connection.

We use a parameter to connect to the databases, so we dont have to estabilish new connections everytime, just need to know if there is any way to reset it, so we dont get DC.